# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#79644 relayoutBoundary=up1

Tags: flutter

I spent 4 hours and cannot fix this error:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#79644 relayoutBoundary=up1
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1687
>   pos 12: 'hasSize'

My code:

```
Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 12,
          alignment: decorationAlignment,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            child: decoration,
          ),
        ),
```

However if i remove `alignment: decorationAlignment` then no error happen.

Can you tell me why?

Thank so much!

Comment: add what is decorationAlignment and decoration's values.

Comment: Seem a default value is `Container()` with out size has passed